# How to add link to Kanban project to show ticket state?

Tags: jira, kanban

In other project types it was possible to insert link into ticket, and status was shown like here:

[image]

But I can not do it with Kanban, why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [Atlassian Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/jira-issue-key-hyperlinking-is-not-working-404324932.html), the project administrator must set the **jira.projectkey.pattern** property to the proper regex expression.

The default regex is `([A-Z][A-Z]+)`.